# get the ID of the the table I click and send it to popup box

Tags: javascript, php, html

and im stuck of what im doing right now,
anyone can help me what i lacked in my code? I planning to have a clickable table with column and row from database, then if a user click the id, a pop up will display with an Action choices like delete, print and update,.

The problem on my code is, it didn't read the ID of the row I click, it always a empty.

here is my code

```
$result = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM tblrv order by ID desc); 

if ($result->rowCount() > 0) {  
      
    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){  
        <tr id="' . $row["ID"] . '"> 
                <td><a onclick="openForm()">'. $row["ID"] .'</a></td> 
                <td>'. $row["RVID"] .'</td> 
                <td>'. $row["RVDate"] .'</td>  
                <td>'. $row["Name"] .'</td>  
                <td>'. $row["ContactNumber"] .'</td>
        </tr>  
     }  
}
```

This is my pop up form

```
 
<div class="loginPopup">
  <div class="formPopup" id="popupForm">
    <div class="formContainer">
      <h2>Choose your Action</h2>
      
         <div id="<?php echo $row["ID"]?>" >
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove">Delete</a>
         </div>
         
       <a class="btn btn-success pull-right" href="/api/print.php/?id="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>" target="_blank"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span> Print</a>
      <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button> 
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the js

```
<script>
function openForm() {
    document.getElementById("popupForm").style.display = "block";
}

function closeForm() {
    document.getElementById("popupForm").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

this is the js for the delete

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".remove").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).parents("div").attr("id");

    if(confirm('Are you sure to Remove Invoice #' + id + ' ')) {
        $.ajax({
           url: "/api/delete.php",
           type: 'GET',
           data: {id: id},
           error: function() {
              alert('Something is wrong');
           },
           success: function(data) {
                $("#"+id).remove();
                Swal.fire(
                'Deleted!',
                'Your file has been deleted.',
                'success'
                );
           }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

The result is always empty,. I hope someone can give me an idea Thanks
Btw, this is working if I manually put the ID and remove the = $row(ID) condition in them, but ofcurz it not the thing I want.

Comment: `$(this).parents("div")` returns *all* the parents. Use `$(this).closest("div")` to get just the nearest parent.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, can you tell me where should i put this sir?

Comment: `.parents` only appears one place in the code. Put it there.

Comment: `var id = $(this).closest("div").attr("id")`

Comment: Or just use `.parent` instead of `.parents`, since it's the immediate enclosing element.

Comment: `<div id="<?php echo $row["ID"]?>" >` won't contain the right ID, or any ID, because `$row` only exists within your PHP `while` loop. This makes no sense. Instead, your `openForm()` JS function should accept the ID of the form as an input, and then use that to retrieve the relevant data (either from the table cells, or perhaps you could conveniently pop it into some data attributes on the button, or from an AJAX request to the server), and write into the correct place in the HTML of the popup.

Comment: sorry im really new in coding, what i have now is the combination of different program that i get in sites, I cant do code from scratch so i dont really know what should i do

Comment: Well, I've just described what you can do, and none of those things are unusual, they would be researchable. You do need to at least _try_ to implement what you need. The process of doing so in itself will help you learn.